# XPATH select by set of possible attribute values

Tags: arrays, select, xpath, set

I have this:

```
<database>

<exercise_muscle id="20" muscleID="1" exerciseID="1" />

<exercise_muscle id="35" muscleID="2" exerciseID="1" />

<exercise_muscle id="50" muscleID="3" exerciseID="2" />

<exercise_muscle id="50" muscleID="4" exerciseID="2" />

</database>
```

And I want to get the exercise_muscle nodes, which have e.g. muscleID value 1, 3 or 4.. so the set of possible values.

I know that I can use "or", but I was hoping there is some better solution.

Answer (score 1):

how about this? (runs using xpath 2.0)

```
/database/exercise_muscle[@muscleID = ('1', '3', '4')]
```

alternatively, you can use

```
/database/exercise_muscle[@muscleID = '1' or @muscleID = '3' or @muscleID = '4']
```

Comment: No, it has to be array of various integers.

Comment: gives me syntax error, but it is basically exactly what I am trying to do... But it does not work.  (check here http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php for instance)